# Bash: Converting Filename 0 - FILENAME.mkv to FILENAME.mkv?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to convert a few files of the form `0 - FILENAME.mkv` to `FILENAME.mkv`, but I'm doing something subtly wrong. This subroutine is in the .bashrc file in my home folder on my Manjaro OS computer. Whenever I update it, the shell it gets executed from does a `source .bashrc` to ensure that it is up to date.

However, the output is empty `""`, but runs properly when executed stand-alone in the shell.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Convert_Filenames_Remove_Leading_Number_Prefix() {
    ConversionTemporary="/run/media/sarah/MSS_EXtended/Conversion Temporary"
    TemporaryDir="/tmp/T1"
    mkdir "$ConversionTemporary"
    mkdir "$TemporaryDir"
    echo "Convert_Filenames_Remove_Leading_Number_Prefix()"
    echo "NOTES: Currently Works on .mp4, .mp3, opus, and .mkv files only. Converts: 0 - FILENAME.EXT -> FILENAME.EXT\n"

    #Copy to conversion temporary for safekeeping
    cp -a "`pwd`" "$ConversionTemporary"
    echo "Copying files to ConversionTemporary complete"
    
    #Main Sequence
    for i in *.{mkv,mp4,mp3,opus}; do 
        filaname=$(echo "$i" | cut -d "-" -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1')
        echo "Result: $filename"
        mv -v "$i" "$filename"
    done
}
```

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, fix any errors, if that doesn't solve it, update your question here with the corrected code. Leave a comment that you have updated it OR leave a comment that it is fixed. Good luck.

Comment: What does "the output is disappointing" mean?

Comment: `echo "$i" | awk -F'[- ]' '{print $NF}'`

Comment: `echo "${i#0 - }"`

Comment: Replace `filaname` with `filename`.

Comment: Wait, @shellter I thought scripts in .bashrc don't have the shebang?

Comment: @SarahSzabo : you need `#!/bin/bash` so https://shellcheck.net will now what shell syntax to validate. Good luck.

Comment: You *might* want to add `local ConversionTemporary TemporaryDir filename i` as the  first line inside your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) in one line:

```
rename 's/.*\s+//' ./*.{mkv,mp4,mp3,opus}
```